# How can I get from Xcode a complete Hierarchy schema for classes, methods, views, inheritance, imports....?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I inherited a very big and complex Objective C project and I am getting crazy at visualizing all the dependencies between classes and methods. 
Is there any external tool known of that helps me display somehow a hierarchy, schema or something similar of all the classes, methods, dependencies, libraries, views,....?

I need it for understanding and future reference. And for mental sanity, in fact. Thank you for any help.

Comment: maybe this: https://github.com/PaulTaykalo/objc-dependency-visualizer ?

Comment: Nice looking graphs!. I have tried a couple of libraries like that one with Graphviz and OmniGraffle. They do (only) show general dependency links between classes. But I would like something more complete and helpful even if not so pretty.